# Google Plus Page API for write

Tags: google-plus

I've some trouble with google plus API for page. I've filled this form (https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup) about one months ago but I haven't recieved any response. There is a way to know if I can obtain this one for my app? There is a guide to use this API?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.googleapis.com/plusPages/v2/people/[id]/activities to post a "note" with a text message, using the same attributes you set by posting to a user profile, via an HTTP REST request. However, problems might occur when attempting to post an Image, then you'd have to have "special" access.